# HTML Table Marquee animation on rows

Tags: html, css, css-animations, marquee

How would I get the rows to not overlap over the table headers when the marquee animation runs?

I've got the code here below also on jsfiddle for anyone that wants to take a look:

https://jsfiddle.net/caddenc/4dxjzb17

```css
.marquee {
    top: 1em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    animation: marquee 10s linear 0s infinite;
}
.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, -100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="marquee">
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row1 - Column 2</td>
      <td>Row1 - Column 3</td>
      <td>Row1 - Column 4</td>
      <td>Row1 - Column 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row2 - Column 2</td>
      <td>Row2 - Column 3</td>
      <td>Row2 - Column 4</td>
      <td>Row2 - Column 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row3 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row3 - Column 2</td>
      <td>Row3 - Column 3</td>
      <td>Row3 - Column 4</td>
      <td>Row3 - Column 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row4 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row4 - Column 2</td>
      <td>Row4 - Column 3</td>
      <td>Row4 - Column 4</td>
      <td>Row4 - Column 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row5 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row5 - Column 2</td>
      <td>Row5 - Column 3</td>
      <td>Row5 - Column 4</td>
      <td>Row5 - Column 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row6 - Column 1</td>
      <td>Row6 - Column 2</td>
      <td>Row6 - Column 3</td>
      <td>Row6 - Column 4</td>
      <td>Row6 - Column 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

I've tried a couple variations on the CSS side to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `z-index: -1;` to `.marquee` and a background color to the `th` elements.

```
th {
  background-color: blue;
}

.marquee {
    top: 1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
    animation: marquee 10s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

alternatively you can also set the `th` element to be higher, then this css is enough.

```
th {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is it working
https://jsfiddle.net/L8r6vfhx/

Comment: thanks! this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the "z-index" property to you animation

Comment: correct, but you would also need to explain that the value must be less than the default z-index of the header, which is zero.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).